# I try to access the tuples values but it says it has too many values to unpack when trying to create a save/load method in Python

Tags: python-3.x, file, save, load

Hi sorry I am new to programming and need help. I have made a simple maths test and I would like to be able to save the score, check the previous highest score and if higher, overwrite the high score.

To the .txt file I have saved "('k', 1.67)" and would like to access the name and the score separately but when I try to access the tuples values, it says it has too many values to unpack.

How can i fix this?

```
**ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)**

def overwrite(highest_score_details):
    with open("score.txt", 'w') as save:
        print(highest_score_details, file=save)


def get_score():
    with open("score.txt", 'r') as load:
        contents = load.readline()
        name_read, score_read = contents
        return contents


name = input("Enter your name: ")
start_time = my_timer()

for i in range(total_questions):
    make_question()

end_time = my_timer()
total_score = time_taken + wrong_answer_penalty

get_score()
highest_score_details = (name, total_score)
overwrite(highest_score_details)
```

Comment: `contents` is a string: a sequence of more than 2 characters.  Why does `get_score` try to assign to `name_read` and `score_read` if it is never going to use them and  just return `contents`?

Comment: I was tying different ways and forgot to remove it, also I dont have much of a clue :P. when I print get_score I can get the tuples data but how can I access the second element?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to use a string as a tuple. `readline` returns a string, which is a collection of characters. In order to properly convert this string to data that can be used the way you need it, you have to define a way to parse it.

Parsing the string will be easier if the format is simpler. If, for example, you changed the way you store the score so that it is just `k,1.67` you could then do the following:

```
contents = load.readline() # read "k,1.67"
tokens = contents.split(",") # convert to ["k","1.67"]
name = tokens[0] # store "k" as the name
score = float(tokens[1]) # convert from the string "1.67" to the value 1.67
return (name, score) # pack the values into a tuple
```

Comment: ok thanks! Now that i have done that i still cant access the functions return variables outside of the function. i am trying "print(get_score.name)" but having no luck :/ have you got any advice for accessing tuple members from a return outside of the function?

Comment: @KevinNisbet First, get_score is a function, so it must be used like `get_score()`
Second, the contents of a tuple like this are accessed by index, not by name. So it would be something like `get_score()[0]` for name and `get_score()[1]` for score